# is there any spring jdbctemplate method which will do insertion and selection of element both?

Tags: java, spring

I have written one procedure which have selection query and insert returning one parameter like

```
String sql = "call insert_feeReceipt("+bean.getStudentName()+","
                + ""+ bean.getStandard()+","
                + ""+ bean.getAmount()+","
                + ""+bean.getModeOfPayment()+","
                + ""+bankName+","
                + ""+bean.getChequeno()+","
                + ""+bean.getDdno()+","
                + ""+date+","
                + ""+bean.getAccount_type_code()+","
                + ""+bean.getCollection_type_code()+", "
                + "@receipt_id)";
```

Which spring jdbc template method is suitable?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use [SimpleJdbcCall](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/SimpleJdbcCall.html)